# .net redirect old cannonical url to a new url format

Tags: asp.net, url, redirect, web-config

So recently a coustomer decided to test a different cannonical url to see if their position changes on search engines. The current cannonical url is as follows `www.mydomain.com/{article-id}` and they want to change only 10 or so articles to `www.mydomain.com/{article-id}/{friendly-url}`.

Example: `www.mydomain.com/123456 -> www.mydomain.com/123456/the-gratest-article-ever`

As I said they only want to change this for a couple of articles, to see if the rankings change.

To properly test if the rankings increase, I have to create a permanent redirect from the old to the new url.

I have tried redirecting in web config using httpRedirect like so:

```
<location path="123456">
    <system.webServer>  
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="/123456/the-gratest-article-ever" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
 </location>
```

But this does not work, as it keeps adding /the-gratest-article-ever one after another, and the whole thing fails with `The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value.`

Is it possible to achive this using web config?

Thanks,
B

Comment: Instead of redirect you could configure a route for the friendly url in the routeConfig file.

Comment: I could do that but that would not tell google that the resource has been moved to a new address, and there would be 2 routes to the same resource...